# How to return an object to the fragment from a nested static asynctask?

Tags: android

I have a fragment that contains a static asynctask class which does some Json data retrieving and parsing - after what I add data to my object `workerObj` which is also a nested parcelable class in my fragment. This object is created inside the fragment and I want to update its data after the asynctask finishes but the error that arrises when I try to assign a new value to `workerObj` inside the `protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject)` method - How to circumvent this - while keeping the asynctask static (it is a must):

`Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field workerObj` when I try in `onPostExecute()` `workerObj = workerObject;`

Summarized code:

```
public class WorkerFragment extends SherlockFragment implements OnClickListener{

DatabaseHandler db;
WorkerParcel workerObj;
......
.....
static class WorkerParcel implements Parcelable {
.....
}

private static class UpdateWorkerAsyncTask extends CustomAsyncTask<WorkerParcel, Integer, JSONObject> {


    private static final String TAG = "DoBackgroundTask";

    private ProgressDialog mProgress;
    private int mCurrProgress;

    private View v;

    Functions workerFunction;
    DatabaseHandler db;

    WorkerParcel workerObject;

    public UpdateWorkerAsyncTask(MainActivity activity, View rootView) {
        super(activity);            
        this.v = rootView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showProgressDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityDetached() {
        if (mProgress != null) {
            mProgress.dismiss();
            mProgress = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityAttached() {
        showProgressDialog();
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
        mProgress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgress.setMessage(" Saljem na server...      ");

        mProgress.setCancelable(true);
        mProgress.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                cancel(true);
            }
        });

        mProgress.show();
        mProgress.setProgress(mCurrProgress);
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(WorkerParcel... params) {

        workerObject = params[0];
        JSONObject json = null;

        // so you need to either pass an instance of the outer class to the
        // inner class method (or its constructor) as a parameter,
        // or create it inside the method.

        if (mActivity != null) {

            // Get workerId from logged worker
            workerFunction = new Functions();
            db = new DatabaseHandler(mActivity);

            if(workerObject.fname.trim().equals(db.retrieveWorker().get("fname"))){
                workerObject.fname = null;
            }
            if(workerObject.lname.trim().equals(db.retrieveWorker().get("lname"))){
                workerObject.lname = null;
            }
            if(workerObject.uname.trim().equals(db.retrieveWorker().get("username"))){
                workerObject.uname = null;
            }
            if(workerObject.pass.trim().equals(db.retrieveWorker().get("pass"))){
                workerObject.pass = null;
            }

                // Get JsonObject from Functions.java
                json = workerFunction.updateWorker(workerObject.workerID, workerObject.fname, workerObject.lname, workerObject.uname, workerObject.pass);           
        }
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);

        if (mActivity != null) {
            mProgress.dismiss();

            try {
                TextView firstname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fnameTxt);
                TextView lastname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lnameTxt);
                TextView username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.unameTxt);
                TextView password = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.passwordTxt);
                TextView lastlogin = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lastLoginTxt);
                TextView errorMsg = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.errorTxt);

                if (jsonObject.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {

                    errorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = jsonObject.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {

                        JSONObject json_worker = jsonObject.getJSONObject("worker");
                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        workerFunction.logoutWorker(mActivity);

                        //Add worker to sqllite db table 
                        //addWorker(String workerId, String fname, String lname, String username, String pass, String lastlog)
                        db.addWorker(json_worker.getString(W_ID), json_worker.getString(W_FNAME), json_worker.getString(W_LNAME), 
                                json_worker.getString(W_USERN), json_worker.getString(W_PASS), json_worker.getString(W_LASTLOGIN));

                        //Retrieve worker acount from local sqllite deb
                        HashMap<String,String> workerDB = db.retrieveWorker();

                        //Add worker to workerObject
                        workerObject = new WorkerParcel(workerDB.get("workerId"),workerDB.get("fname"),workerDB.get("lname"),workerDB.get("username")
                                ,workerDB.get("pass"),workerDB.get("lastlog"));

                        firstname.setText(workerObject.fname);
                        lastname.setText(workerObject.lname);
                        username.setText(workerObject.uname);
                        password.setText(workerObject.pass);
                        lastlogin.setText(workerObject.lastlog);

                        workerObj = workerObject;

                    } else {
                        // Error in updating
                        errorMsg.setText("Error occured in updating account");
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an interface

```
public interface GetObject {
    void onGetObject(WorkerParcel workerObj);
}
```

force your aysnctask to implement it and use the callback to retrieve the results

```
private static class UpdateWorkerAsyncTask extends CustomAsyncTask<WorkerParcel, Integer, JSONObject> {
  GetObject mlistener;
  public UpdateWorkerAsyncTask(MainActivity activity, View rootView, GetObject listener) {
        mlistener = listener;
        // your code
  }

  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {

          if (mlistener != null) {
                mlistener.onGetObject(workerObject);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a question - is there a possibility to do it somehow directly to the fragment like I did it when sending data from fragment to activity - ´((MainActivity)getActivity()).onUpdateFinish(workObj);´  - how to get a public Fragment inside a static nested class etc.. thanks

Comment: well this way with interfaces is sort of decoupling ...but when I used to call a `dialogfragment` from my `mainActivity` - I would enter a value into the edittext of the `dialogfragment` and click the button to return the value back to the `mainActivity` - in my dialogFragment the onClick method would just call a method from my `MainActivity` passing the string value from digalogs edittext -  like this `((MainActivity)getActivity()).onUpdateFinish(editvalue);` - is this possible in my case instead of making these interfaces it would be like `getFragment().onUpdateFinsih(workObj)`